# Comparing two lists and getting the difference in numbers

Tags: python, list, numbers, compare

I'm trying to understand what the most efficient way to take two lists e.g.

`[u'25.78', u'13.39', u'11.93', u'14.97', u'14.34', u'21.08', u'13.24', u'13.11', u'', u'19.45', u'17.56', u'20.57', u'28.50', u'24.38', u'31.13', u'17.20', u'18.52', u'6.42', u'17.31']`

and

`[u'20.77', u'24.08', u'17.66', u'14.63', u'24.40', u'42.14', u'21.93', u'30.37', u'15.20', u'21.94', u'34.20', u'18.47', u'19.05', u'24.31', u'13.55', u'14.44', u'32.53', u'18.00', u'19.95']`

And get a new list with the following:

`[u'5.01',u'-10.69',u'-5.73']` and so on..

My brain just isn't comprehending how to do this logically. I keep wanting to refer to a `for` loop but I am trying to for a `for` loop inside of another `for` loop and it's messing me up.

Answer (score 6):

The key is it iterate over both lists *at the same time*.  [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) will pair items from each list.

Given `listA` and `listB`:

```
[u'%0.2f' % (float(x) - float(y)) for x, y in zip(listA, listB)]
```

Comment: could you pls advise why this code not working ?  [(float(str(x)) - float(str(y))) for x, y in zip(a, b)]

Comment: @ShawnZhang:  I wouldn't know without seeing `a` and `b` and a traceback.

Comment: they are from two list data in to this question. ERROR msg : ValueError: could not convert string to float: ... why float() not working on string ? ..quite confusing .

Comment: I'm testing this and it's not working.  Have you tested this?

Comment: @ShawnZhang: It chokes on the empty string (`u''`).

Comment: `[u'%0.2f' % (float(x) - float(y)) for x, y in zip(listA, listB) if not (x=='' or y=='')]`  - doesn't work for one '' and other not, though.